# Redirect domain's content to another domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, .htaccess

1) How would I redirect user1.domain.com to display domain.com/user?id=1 content?

2) How would I redirect domain1.com to display sub.domain2.com's content?

I have both domains on the same server/host, so I don't think changing A records in the DNS is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that you are using Apache.

> 1) How would I redirect user1.domain.com to display domain.com/user?id=1 content?

Something like the following should work although I haven't tested it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^user1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule . http://domain.com/user?id=1 [L,R]
```

> 2) How would I redirect domain1.com to display sub.domain2.com's content?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.com
  Redirect 302 / http://sub.domain2.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! One more minor question.. how would I make it so

Comment: You could add those statements to either .htaccess or your apache configuration, depending whether you have root access or not.